# Why Amazon, Walmart, Fab and others have "login" only under main menu? Why not both login and register?

Tags: login

A lot of e-commerce stores have login link only under main menu on their mobile apps or website. Why do they hide register from main menu?
UPD: What do you think guys, what is the best option:

1. Just "Login" link

2. "Login" and "Register" as 2 separate links

3. "Login/Register" together as one link to Login popup.

4. other

 I need your opinion. Thx
[image]

Comment: Here is my thoughts. 
1. It's possible that Amazon and others just tested number of clicks to "Register" from Main menu and the number was significantly low. In that case it makes sense to remove "Register" from Main Menu
2. The second reason might be to remove negative feelings because "Register" link is always associated with long annoying form.

Comment: 3. One more reason I could imagine is the statement "Ask login/register only when needed". Why customers need to sign In or register? Probably to Go to their Account or make a purchase. So why do not ask them to login/register when they trying to make a purchase or see their order history?

Answer (score 3):

E-commerce's #1 goal is to get **users to buy**. They want to reduce the noise but still have login available for those who do have an account.

You also have to remember that registration isn't vital, purchasing is. Registration commonly happens after the checkout has occurred (as a secondary or even a tertiary action).

Comment: But at the same time registration is very important for business. Many businesses prefer to have registered customers to have their emails and send them some promo stuff. Also business wants to collect all the possible info about customer. For example, gender, age, location etc.
So from business prospective registrations is very important.

Comment: That's true, but you also have to understand why people come to the site in the first place. They want to **buy**, not register. You can still collect that information after checkout. That seems to be the more logical solution why people are only incorporating registration after checking out. It's not as important.

Comment: > Registration commonly happens after the checkout has occurred (as a
> secondary or even a tertiary action). Registration commonly happens before or during checkout than post-purchase. It's additional "nice" feature to have it in post-purchase screen. Registration is pretty high up in priority list for ecommerce, particulary those customers who actually made purchase with your store in the past. Customer who made purchase has much higher chance of coming back to the site for more. So to rely solely on post-purchase registration which user is more likely exit w/o registration is a risky decisi

Comment: Anyone have a ratio of #logins vs. #registrations on a usual e-commerce website ? I tend to agree with this proposed answer, but do not have any factual data that could confirm or deny this opinion.

Comment: @dRqmist not saying to solely rely on that, but that's why it's not as present as it is anywhere else. Login is front and center for those returning people. And usually people sign up after purchasing, not before, because there is an added risk for the user if they did that.

Comment: We do what @Majo0od says and for the reasons he mentions. And we do it a lot, almost as exclusive approach unless requested otherwise. So far, tracking and testing shows this is the correct approach for us, with results up to 200% better, so no plans to change it in the near future. Think of the process: I want to buy something, then noise after noise, distraction after distraction  is added because the site wants me to register first. On the other hand, I want to buy an item. I do it. My info (needed to purchase the item) is added and registers me as client. Done.

Comment: To add to @Devin's comment. The only reason people register is because they know that the product and or services that they are purchasing is of great value to them. Without even getting either or, a registration will be meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess :)
Users associate Sign up and Register to be part of Login because very frequently Login and Sign up are on the same page/component. Additional examples are Spotify and Yahoo. Google also makes assumption that people may have multiple google accounts and allows to sign up easily from sign in page.
I think a brief answer is that people are familiar with the pattern of Login and Sign up together and there is no reason to separate the two unless it's a promotional product page and you really want to cater to brand new users and make Sign Up one step easier.

Comment: I see what you mean. But I why do not have still one link but looks like this "Sign In/Register". It's more informative and more clear for customers who are looking for "Register" button. We always assume that customers are not power users. So why do not show them more clear title.

Comment: I don't agree with that. The label login means *login* and nothing else. If that's the case, they should label it "Login/Register" instead.

Comment: I think since so many sites put sign up and login on the same page, Login has a more broad meaning for a lot of people. But Login/Register might be a good option too, I am not arguing with that :)